# Double Integral Query

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

Looking for advice/direction on the following query please.

Ok, here is the problem:

If we have

$$ \vec{T} = \frac{\mu IbN}{4\pi L}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}C\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(\theta)}{p^3}d\theta dz $$

Where

$$ 
C = Z-z \\
p^{-3} = (1 + \frac{3bX}{X^2 + C^2} \cos(\theta))(X^2+C^2)^{-3/2}
$$

Now, after integration the result I should have is

$$
T = \frac{\mu}{4\pi}\frac{M}{L}X\left[(X^2 + C^2)^{-3/2} \right]_{-L/2-Z}^{L/2-Z}
$$

Where

$$
M = Ib^2\pi N
$$

I would appreciate if someone could verify that I'm performing the Math correctly and if not, where am I going wrong...

Ok, now here is my attempt to obtain the solution:

Step 1 is to substitute in for $ p^3 $:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(\theta)}{p^3}d\theta  & = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(\theta)}{(1 + \frac{3bX}{X^2 + C^2} \cos(\theta))(X^2+C^2)^{-3/2}}d\theta \\
 & = \frac{1}{(X^2+C^2)^{-3/2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(\theta)}{(1 + \frac{3bX}{X^2 + C^2} \cos(\theta))}d\theta \\
& = \frac{1}{(X^2+C^2)^{-3/2}}\frac{2\pi (C^2 +X^2)}{3Xb} \\
& = \frac{2\pi (C^2 + X^2)^{5/2}}{3Xb}
\end{align}$$

Step 2 - Substitute into the double integral above:

$$
\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}C\frac{2\pi (C^2 + X^2)^{5/2}}{3Xb}dz
$$

Now, as previously stated $ C = Z - z $, therefore:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}C\frac{2\pi (C^2 + X^2)^{5/2}}{3Xb}dz & = \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}(Z-z)\frac{2\pi ((Z-z)^2 + X^2)^{5/2}}{3Xb}dz \\
& = \frac{2\pi}{3Xb}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}(Z-z)((Z-z)^2 + X^2)^{5/2}dz
\end{align}$$

Ok, now this is where I could do with a sanity check...

1) Am I correct with my Math so far?

2) To perform the integration above, what is the best method to use?

3) Is there a way to simplify the integral at all?

I cannot see how to get from here:

$$
\frac{\mu IbN}{4\pi L}\frac{2\pi}{3Xb}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}(Z-z)((Z-z)^2 + X^2)^{5/2}dz
$$

to here:

$$
T = \frac{\mu}{4\pi}\frac{M}{L}X\left[(X^2 + C^2)^{-3/2} \right]_{-L/2-Z}^{L/2-Z}
$$

From the given solution we have:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mu}{4\pi}\frac{M}{L} & = \frac{\mu Ib^2\pi N}{4\pi L} 
\end{align}$$

From my Math so far we have:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mu IbN}{4\pi L}\frac{2\pi}{3Xb} & = \frac{2\mu Ib\pi N}{12\pi LXb} \\
& = \frac{\mu I\pi N}{6\pi LX}
\end{align}$$

Something seems sadly amiss - any advice?

For the Integral, I cannot see how to get from:

$$
\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}(Z-z)((Z-z)^2 + X^2)^{5/2}dz
$$

to:

$$
\left[(X^2 + C^2)^{-3/2} \right]_{-L/2-Z}^{L/2-Z}
$$

Not really looking for the answers, just some pointers as to where I maybe going wrong.  In particular the correct method of solution for the Integral above.

Thankyou.

Ok, continuing on from the comments recieved...

As noted:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\cos(\theta)}{p^3} & = \cos(\theta)*p^{-3} \\
& = \cos(\theta) * (1 + \frac{3bX}{X^2 + C^2} \cos(\theta))(X^2+C^2)^{-3/2}
\end{align}
$$

So if I revisit the first integral we have:

Step 1:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(\theta)}{p^3}d\theta  & = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(\theta) * (1 + \frac{3bX}{X^2 + C^2} \cos(\theta))(X^2+C^2)^{-3/2}d\theta \\
 & = (X^2+C^2)^{-3/2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(\theta) * (1 + \frac{3bX}{X^2 + C^2} \cos(\theta))d\theta \\
& = (X^2+C^2)^{-3/2} \frac{3\pi Xb}{C^2+X^2} \\
& = (3\pi Xb)(C^2+X^2)^{-5/2}
\end{align}$$

Step 2 is to apply this within the second integral, so we have:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}3\pi XbC(C^2+X^2)^{-5/2}dz & = 3\pi Xb\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}C(C^2+X^2)^{-5/2}dz \\
& = 3\pi Xb\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}(Z-z)((Z-z)^2+X^2)^{-5/2}dz
\end{align}$$

Now, is there something 'special' about the integral above?  Mathcad will not solve this - is there some elliptical integral involved in this?

Any advice/pointers appreciated.

Ok, final update and hopefully I will show how to get the result I was looking for...

Step 1:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(\theta)}{p^3}d\theta  & = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(\theta) * (1 + \frac{3bX}{X^2 + C^2} \cos(\theta))(X^2+C^2)^{-3/2}d\theta \\
 & = (X^2+C^2)^{-3/2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(\theta) * (1 + \frac{3bX}{X^2 + C^2} \cos(\theta))d\theta \\
& = (X^2+C^2)^{-3/2} \frac{3\pi Xb}{C^2+X^2} \\
& = (3\pi Xb)(C^2+X^2)^{-5/2}
\end{align}$$

Step 2 is to apply this within the second integral, so we have:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}3\pi XbC(C^2+X^2)^{-5/2}dz & = 3\pi Xb\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}C(C^2+X^2)^{-5/2}dz \\
& = 3\pi Xb\left[\frac{8}{3*(L^2+4*X^2-4*ZL+4*Z^2}^{-3/2}-\frac{8}{3*(L^2+4*X^2+4*ZL+4*Z^2}^{-3/2}\right] \\
& = \frac{3\pi Xb}{3}\left[\left[(Z-\frac{L}{2})^2+X^2\right]^{-3/2} - \left[(Z+\frac{L}{2})^2+X^2\right]^{-3/2}\right] \\
& = \pi Xb\left[\left[(Z-z)^2+X^2)\right]^{-3/2}\right]_{-L/2-Z}^{L/2-Z}
\end{align}$$

The original result required was:

$$\begin{align}
T & = \frac{\mu}{4\pi}\frac{M}{L}X\left[(X^2 + C^2)^{-3/2} \right]_{-L/2-Z}^{L/2-Z} \\
& = \frac{\mu Ib^2\pi N}{4\pi L}X\left[(X^2 + C^2)^{-3/2} \right]_{-L/2-Z}^{L/2-Z}
\end{align}$$

And we now have:

$$\begin{align}
T & = \frac{\mu IbN}{4\pi L}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}C\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(\theta)}{p^3}d\theta dz \\
& = \frac{\mu Ib^2\pi NX}{4\pi L}\left[\left[(Z-z)^2+X^2)\right]^{-3/2}\right]_{-L/2-Z}^{L/2-Z} \\
& = \frac{\mu Ib^2\pi N}{4\pi L}X\left[(X^2 + C^2)^{-3/2} \right]_{-L/2-Z}^{L/2-Z}
\end{align}$$

Which I think is correct?

Answer (score 2):

The main error in your calculation I see, is that of your definition and implementation of $p$. You define that $$p^{-3} = (1 + \frac{3bX}{X^2 + C^2} \cos(\theta))(X^2+C^2)^{-3/2}$$ and you have $\frac{\cos \theta}{p^3}$ which is equivalent to saying $\cos\theta \cdot p^{-3}$. When you go to substitute in $p$, you still divide $\cos\theta$ by $p^{-3}$ rather than multiplying it. As such, you will result in this:

$$
\frac{\cos\theta}{p^3}  = \cos\theta\cdot p^{-3}\\
p^{-3} = (1 + \frac{3bX}{X^2 + C^2} \cos(\theta))(X^2+C^2)^{-3/2} \\
\text{Therefore, when you substitute in }p \text{ you get: }\\
\cos\theta\cdot (1 + \frac{3bX}{X^2 + C^2} \cos(\theta))(X^2+C^2)^{-3/2}
$$

Comment: Ahhhh.... Ok, what a fool I am.  Please see the edited question above with my new Math.

Comment: I put your new 'end' integral into Mathematica, gave me the result of $\frac{3 b^2 C I \mu  N X}{4
   \left(C^2+X^2\right)^{5/2}}$. So there appears to be nothing so 'special' to it. Not sure why MathCad would not be solving it.

Comment: Thankyou for that.  I will carry on tonight and update the original post.  This is a personal challenge which I won't give up!  On the Mathcad, it seems that Mathcad 15 cannot handle the integral yet Mathcad 2001i (much older) can.  I might put this to PTC and see if it is a bug.  Mathematica is downloading as I type, seems much more powerful.

Comment: Hi,  I think I have it sussed now.  Please see the original question.  On the Mathcad, I've actually discovered a bug in the underlying MuPad Symbolic engine.  The integral is solvable in an older version of Mathcad which used the Maple Symbolic engine.  I am in the process of logging a bug report with PTC.  Thankyou for your help, it is appreciated.